# Jprofiler: how to detach jprofiler from a java process

Tags: jprofiler

I am  evaluating Jprofiler. 
In this process, i tried to attach a profiling scheme to a java process on a remote machine.
it provided a  profiling port number, using which could connect to remote process and proceed.
But, once a profiling port is attached, i did not find anyway to de-associate the profiling port from the java process.

I would like to know if there is anyway to remove the profiling port from the java process without killing  the java process.

Would appreciate your response.
Thank you very much.

Dev

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that because the JVM does not provide a way to unload an agent.

Comment: I am genuinely interested: In your country, would I say "Thank you Singh", always using the last name to address someone in an informal way? Because in most English-speaking societies you have to use the first name or alternatively add a "Mr" before the last name.

Comment: Hi Mr Ingo Kegel,  both are accepted now a days. but preferably, we would address anybody with  Mr/Mrs first name or last name. So, first, my apologies, if it would have hurt you. Second, i will take care from now onwards.